# Why does $n*T_n = m*T_m$ imply $T_\text{n+m} = 0$?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I was fiddling around with Arithmetic Progressions and I noticed this pattern.

\begin{align}
n*T_n = m*T_m \implies T_\text{n+m} = 0
\end{align}

where $n, m \in \{0, \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ and $n \neq m$.

I could prove that it's true like so:-

\begin{align*}
    & m*T_m = n*T_n \\
    & \Rightarrow m\{a + (m-1)d\} = n\{a + (n-1)d\} \\
    & \Rightarrow ma + m^2d - md = na + n^2d - nd \\
    & \Rightarrow am - an + m^2d - n^2d - md + nd = 0 \\
    & \Rightarrow a(m-n) + (m^2-n^2)d - (m-n)d = 0 \\
    & \Rightarrow a(m-n) + (m-n)(m+n)d - (m-n)d = 0 \\
    & \Rightarrow (m-n)\{a + (m+n)d - d\} = 0 \\
    & \Rightarrow (m-n)\{a + (m+n-1)d\} = 0 \\
    & \Rightarrow a + (m+n-1)d = 0 \\
    & \Rightarrow T_{m+n} = 0
\end{align*}

But I couldn't figure out the intuitive reasoning behind it. Could you help me out using as little machinery as possible?

Comment: What is the definition of $T_n$?

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz The $n$th term of an AP.

Comment: As written, the claim isn't true for constant, non-zero, sequence. Why not just write it as $nT_n = mT_m \iff (n-m)T_{m+n} = 0$, when $T_n = an + b$.

Comment: Oh ok! Well, have you tried using induction proof?

Comment: I think OP has stated that they can prove it algebraically, but is looking for an intuitive explanation.

Comment: @Joshua, no offense, but you should read the question.

Comment: @Ennar That is not true. If the AP is constant, then the condition will only be met when $n = m$. It's clearly been stated that $n \neq m$.

Comment: Can you add the simple algebraic manipulations that you used? Don't want to write an answer less simple and less intuitive than that. Thanks.

Comment: It is true, that's not how you write it and you did not clearly state that $n\neq m$, you wrote that you proved it when $n\neq m$, which means that you quite literally proved different statement than what you wrote. You can write what I have or write $\forall m\neq n$.

Comment: @peterwhy I added the proof.

Comment: @Ennar I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intuitive explanation with up to middle school level analysis: First we rewrite $T_n = T_1 + (n-1)a$ as $T(x) = ax + b$, where $b = T_1$, and $x = n - 1$.

$x(T(x)) = ax^2 + bx = Q(x)$, which is a quadratic expression. And, if for some $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $nT(n) = mT(m)$, then we can think of this as saying:
$$an^2 + bn = am^2 + bm \\Q(n) = Q(m)$$
We also want to say that if above is true, then $m+n = \frac{-b}{a}$, since that is the root to our linear function $T(x)$. However, you may notice that $\frac{-b}{a}$ is also a root to our quadratic expression $Q(x) = ax^2 +bx = x(ax + b)$. Hence (since $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \not = n$, $ m + n \not = 0$ so) if $Q(m+n) = 0$, then $T(m+n) = 0$.

So our final question becomes, why is it that if $Q(m) = Q(n)$, then $Q(m+n) = 0$? Because we know our apex is at $\frac{-b}{2a}$ and since $m$ and $n$ should be on opposite side of it, we can represent $m = \frac{-b}{2a} + d$ and $n = \frac{-b}{2a} - d$, WLOG. Then, $$Q(m+n)= Q(\frac{-b}{2a} + d + \frac{-b}{2a} -d) = Q(\frac{-2b}{2a}) = Q(\frac{-b}{a}) = 0$$
And since $Q(m+n) = 0$, $T(m+n) = 0$. $\square$

Im not sure if this is as intuitive as you liked, but this is about as good of a picture as I can paint for you. Hopefully this helps, let me know if I can fix it in any way!

Answer (score 2):

From the property of AP or linear functions, as worded by [@preferred_anon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27150/preferred-anon),

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{T_{n+m} - T_n}{m} &= \frac{T_{n+m} - T_m}{n} &&(=d)\tag{*}\\
nT_{n+m} - nT_n &= mT_{n+m} - mT_m\\
nT_{n+m} &= mT_{n+m}
\end{align*}$$

This means that either $T_{n+m} = 0$ or $m=n$ (rejected).

(The $(*)$ fractions are undefined if either of $m,n$ is zero, but the next line still holds.)

---

Or as I initially presented it,

$$\begin{align*}
T_{n+m} - T_n &= T_m - T_0\\
T_{n+m} &= T_n + \left(T_m - T_0\right)\tag1\\
n T_{n+m} &= nT_n + n\left(T_m - T_0\right)\\
&= mT_m + n\cdot md\\
&= mT_m + m\left(T_n - T_0\right)\\
&= m\left(T_m + T_n - T_0\right)\\
&= m T_{n+m}&&\text{using line $(1)$}
\end{align*}$$

This means that either $T_{n+m} = 0$ or $m=n$ (rejected).

Comment: To check, this is still just "algebraic manipulation" right? (And arguably, you're doing very similar, if not the same, steps as OP, just disguised in another form) $\quad$  To what extent are you showcasing the "intuitive reasoning"?

Comment: @CalvinLin I suppose this may be seen as a rephrase or "disguise". As the OP would like "the intuitive reasoning behind it", so I tried to shorten their proof and group some of their overly expanded forms back to actual AP terms.

Comment: I don't think this is a mere rephrasing of the OP's work. Another rewording still would be $$\frac{T_{n+m}-T_n}{m} = \frac{T_{n+m}-T_m}{n}$$
which is immediately obvious for an AP, and pretty easily implies the result. In particular this doesn't use the "general formula" for an AP as the OP does.

Comment: @preferred_anon Thanks, do you think I should include your rewording in this answer, or do you prefer to write an answer with it?

Comment: Thanks a lot @peterwhy, your way is much more intuitive than just brute forcing through the equation like I did.

Comment: @preferred_anon You could think about writing an answer with that, it is very helpful.

Comment: @HerrAlvé I wanted to graph $y = T_x$ and represent products like $nT_n = mT_m$ etc. into areas, but I haven't found a satisfactory graphical proof yet. I also prefer the comment from preferred_anon than this answer.

Comment: @peterwhy Feel free to include my comment in your answer! It's too similar to yours for me to post it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This essentially uses Vieta's formula, which arguably is more machinery than "algebraic manipulation". Though to be fair, almost any other method will be more machinery than expand and check, and this approach yields some nice results.

1. Think of $T_n$ as just a linear equation $T_n = (a-d) + nd$.

   - That's all that really matters here.
   - $ d \neq 0$ by assumption.
2. $n \times T_n = m \times T_m$ for $ n \neq m$ means that $n,m$ are the distinct roots to the quadratic $ dx^2 + (a-d) x  = k$ for some $k$.

   - $ d \neq 0 $ means we have a quadratic.
3. **Lemma:** If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, then the sum of the (possibly complex, with multiplicity) solutions to $f(x) = K$ is a constant for any constant $K$.

   - Proof is left to the reader. Look up Vieta's formula if you're stuck.
4. **Corollary:** Let $ f(x) = dx^2 + (a-d) x$, then the sum of solutions to $f(x) = K$ is $n+m$.
5. **Corollary:** Apply this to $K = 0$, since  $ x= 0 $ is clearly a root to $f(x) = 0$, so the other root is $n+m - 0 $.

   - Thus, $ (n+m)  T_{n+m} =  0 \times T_0 = 0$.
6. Bonus Corollary: $nT_n = mT_m \Leftrightarrow p T_p = (n+m - p) T_{n+m - p } $ for all $p$.

   - Your result is the special case of $p = 0 $.
7. Bonus Corollary: $nT_n = mT_m$ iff $\frac{a-d}{d} = n+m$.
8. Bonus Corollary: At no point did we require that $n, m$ are integers. So this also holds for (say) $\frac{1}{2} T_{\frac{1}{2} } = \pi T_\pi$, even though there isn't a corresponding arithmetic progression term.

   - Which is why I said at the start to just think of $T_n$ as a linear equation.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Calvin! Although this is really interesting, I still cannot wrap my head around why the statement is true, on an intuitive level. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: @HerrAlvé Do you agree/understand: If $f(x) $ is a quadratic, then the sum of the (possibly complex) solutions to $f(x) = K$ is a constant?   $\quad$ This is a slightly complicated idea, whose proof is essentially Vieta's formula but I don't know if that's too advanced for you.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that.

Comment: @HerrAlvé Alright, I've rephrased using that as the main idea. Does this help?

Comment: That does help a lot, actually. Thank you so much! And sorry for the delay in me responding -- there's a lot to do on a Christmas Eve, isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, at no point during the proof, you used the fact that your coefficients were integers. In fact, you can deduce this from a simple geometric argument and calculus.

Consider the function $f(x) = x(a(x-1)+d)$, whose graph is a parabola. If you find two different points $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then their midpoint $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ will necessarily be where $f$ attains its extremum. In other words, $f'(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}) = 0$, and so $a(x_1+x_2 - 1) + d$.